# Value casting when extending Generic parent

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Why does subclass still need a casting to access value from his `Generic` parent's properties ? Any particular reason ? have a look :

```
    class a<U, T> {    

    public U u;   
    public T t;    
    public a(U u, T t) {
        this.u = u;
        this.t = t;            
    }

    public U getU(){
         return u;
     }   
   }


class b extends a { 
    public b(String u, Integer t) { super(u, t); }


     // Here I call b's parent method where casting occurs
    public String get(){
    return (String) getU(); // Here's the cast
    }
}
```

I know that the type returned by `super.getU()` is `U` , but Isn't `b` inherited from `a` which means `a`'s properties will be visible to its children classes!? Plus superclass' constructor had been refered by super(11111,"aString"); ? Isn't it enough to tell `b`'s parent that "I'm your child passing an `Integer` & a `String` " , it looks to me like there is no relation between class "a" and class "b"

***UDPATE** : code typos had been fixed ,sorry it happened because i typed in hurry.

Comment: without  specifying the types of U and T they will now consider as an Object type upon compile time, thus you need to cast it because U is an object type not a string type

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin, that's why I asked for , why I still need to specify the types of U and T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your edit, the problem is you are using a raw type in your `extends` declaration.

```
class b extends a {
```

When using a raw type, for example `a`, all type parameters are erased. When invoking the parent class' `getU()` method, the return type is erased to its upper bound, from `U` to `Object. Your subclass method has a return type of`String`, but you attempt to return an`Object`. That's why the cast is necessary.

Read

[What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Don't use a raw type. Parameterize your type usage and the case won't be necessary..

```
class b extends a<String, Integer> {

    public b(String u, Integer t) {
        super(u, t);

    }    

    public String get() {
        return getU();  
    }
}
```

Comment: oh yeah that's it , it made me confused because the super(String.., Integer..) didn't show me any error , so i assumed that class b will just understand the type. Thanks ! I missed that one on internship interview this afternoon, but well nvm

Comment: @Fev The compiler would typically show a warning for raw types. Now you know. You'll get them next time. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

There is **no need for cast** here, as you expected.

I think that your actual problem is that when you do:

```
B extends A<String, Integer>
```

... knowing that:

```
class A<U, T>
```

... then `U` is `String` and `T` is `Integer`. Thus, your method `B#callGetU()` should return a `String`, and not an `Integer`. ;)

---

Here's an example of how your `B` class should look like:

```
class B extends A<String, Integer> {

    public B(final String u, final Integer t) {  // <- Swapped Integer and String
        super("aString", 11111); // <- Swapped 11111 and "aString"
    }

    // Here I call b's parent method here where casting occurs
    public String callGetU() {   // <- U is String, not Integer
        return getU();           // <- Removed unnecessary cast
    }
}
```